# Access model's properties of selected option outside autocomplete tag

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

Based on Angular example in its official website, section "Form Controls > Autocomplete" [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples), I wonder how can we get model's properties to display outside the tag `<mat-autocomplete>` somewhere in the template ?

The goal is to to have something like this :

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>


  <p> {{state.name}} </p>

</form>


 <p> {{state.name}} </p>
```

I suspect this could be done with `ngModel` functionality somehow, but how ?

Angular version is the same as official demo : 8.2.3

Comment: why cant you use the MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent to call a function that adds the selected info to an object that displays the info?

Comment: I tried it, the problem is that i have to send the model itself as selected option to handle it in the component, and to specify the model here `[value]="state"` which then display on selection `[Object object]` in autocomplete input !

Comment: can you do a StackBlitz?

Comment: Here's the basic official demo : https://angular-ftaatg.stackblitz.io/

Comment: there's not much i can to with that. Can you put your code on stackblitz.

Comment: I have the same code as the official demo. What kind of code exactly you wanna add to the online demo ?

Comment: sorry for that, didn't realize i could see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjfbks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts)

I've added this to the html
(onSelectionChange)="someFunction($event)"

[matAutocomplete]="auto"

changed to [value]="state"

and changed   private _filterStates in the ts file

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's working as expected. Besides, as my Angular version "8.2.3" is different from yours in StackBlitz's demo "8.2.9", I had to replace the event attribute `(onSelectionChange)` by `(optionSelected)` to make it work properly.